# How to check whether a line contains string from list and print the matched string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
stringList = {"NppFTP", "FTPBox" , "tlp"}
uniqueLine = open('unique.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore')
for line in uniqueLine:
    if any(s in line for s in stringList):
        print ("match found")
```

Does anyone know how can I `print` the matched `string` from `stringList` rather than any `string`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing what unique.txt looks like it sounds like you could just nest your for and if

```
stringList = {"NppFTP", "FTPBox" , "tlp"}
uniqueLine = open('unique.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore')

for line in uniqueLine:
    for s in stringList:
        if s in line:
            print ("match found for " + s)
```

Comment: Yeah! I could easily do that, just like rearranging my code! thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the following trick:

```
import numpy as np

stringList = {"NppFTP", "FTPBox" , "tlp"}
uniqueLine = open('unique.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore')
for line in uniqueLine:
    # temp will be a boolean list
    temp = [s in line for s in stringList]
    if any(temp):
        # when taking the argmax, the boolean values will be 
        # automatically casted to integers, True -> 1 False -> 0
        idx = np.argmax(temp)
        print (stringList[idx])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use set `intersections`

```
stringList = {"NppFTP", "FTPBox" , "tlp"}
uniqueLine = open('unique.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore')
for line in uniqueLine:
    found = set(line) & stringList
    if found:
        print("Match found: {}".format(found.pop()))
    else:
        continue
```

Note: This doesn't account for the fact if there is more than one match however.

Answer (score 0):

First, I encourage you to use `with` in oder to open a file, and avoid issues if your program crashes at some point. Second, you can apply `filter`. Last, if you are using Python 3.6+, you can use f-strings.

```
stringList = {"NppFTP", "FTPBox" , "tlp"}

with open('unique.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as uniqueLine:
    for line in uniqueLine:
        strings = filter(lambda s: s in line, stringList)

        for s in strings:
            print (f"match found for {s}")
```